# Unable to run rails commands due to invalid URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman, addressable-gem

Whenever I try to run `foreman run rails server` I receive the following error message from rails:

`Absolute URI missing hierarchical segment: 'http://:9200' (Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError)`.

I realize that 'http://:9200' is an invalid URL, but part of the problem is that not even sure why my absolute URI is 'http://:9200'.

I looked through the Addressable gem's documentation, but I didn't see anything relevant that would solve my issue.

This isn't my project originally, but is a project I pulled from github, so there's a lot going on that I'm not aware of. But I do know that it uses the Addressable gem as well as foreman. I'm just trying to run the server locally.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like it's missing the server name, which would be something like localhost - is there a setting for that somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I think the server name was supposed to be put into the ElasticSearch_URL environment variable, which would have created a valid URI (see my answer given below). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was a problem with ElasticSearch. The ElasticSearch_URL environment variable was not set, and that led to an invalid URI.

This problem was identified by the numbers ":9200" in the URL, which is the default port that ElasticSearch uses.